# I want to know a better way to replace() Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, replace

How can I get a better way?
josn :

```
home = '{u'1p': u'2', u'2p': u'0', u'rs': u'2', u'3p': u'0', u'penalty': u'0', u'fe': u'2', u'ord': u'2', u'ot':u'0'}'
```

I want the result.

```
home = '1p: 2, 2p: 0, rs: 2, 3p: 0, penalty: 0, fe: 2, ord: 2, ot:0'
```

I tried this.

```
home= sport.get("home")
home= str(home).replace("{","")
home= str(home).replace("}","")
home= str(home).replace("u'","")
home= str(home).replace("'","")
```

Comment: but your `home` variable will initially throw `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Update your question

Comment: Why not just parse it using `json.loads(...)` and produce the same result via iteration?

Comment: Please post some working code. Where are you getting your data from -- a valid JSON file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
d = json.loads(home)
print(','.join('%s: %s' % tup for tup in d.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
res = ''.join('{}: {}, '.format(k, v) for k, v in ast.literal_eval(home).items())[:-2]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
'1p: 2, 2p: 0, rs: 2, 3p: 0, penalty: 0, fe: 2, ord: 2, ot: 0'
```

Answer (score -1):

So, time for some string magic:

```
home = "{u'1p': u'2', u'2p': u'0', u'rs': u'2', u'3p': u'0', u'penalty': u'0', u'fe': u'2', u'ord': u'2', u'ot':u'0'}"
import ast
home = ''.join(['{}: {}, '.format(k,v) for k,v in ast.literal_eval(home).items()]).strip(', ')
```

This will land you with `home = '1p: 2, 2p: 0, rs: 2, 3p: 0, penalty: 0, fe: 2, ord: 2, ot: 0'`

But in essence, this is a one-line workaround for doing the exact same thing you were doing with the replaces. It converts the string `home` to a dictionary to use in a comprehension. In the end, the dictionary is replaced by a string. I do not see what the use would be for removing a piece of structure engrained in the json, except if it is for printing purposes, which can be done more efficiently in a dict comprehension.

Comment: The `eval(...)` is a no-no IMO.

Comment: Okay, okay, if you do not trust the source from which you get the json, you should indeed not use `eval` as that can quickly lead to security issues..@клйкбаутоьмажазвайкукас updated to use the more safe `literal_eval` from the Python in-built `ast`

Answer (score -1):

You could use regex

```
home = sport.get("home")
home = re.sub(r'[{}\'u]+','', home)
```